# fail to create unique constraint with hibernate annotation in a postgres database

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, annotations, unique-constraint

Im using hibernate, postgres 9.1, and i'm trying to add a unique constraint via hibernate annotation (not adding explicitly in the database)

However, db ignores the unique annotation and doesn't create the constraint. I also tried add the contraint in the @Table annotation but failed too

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {   

 @Id
 @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
 @Type(type="java.lang.Long")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PERSON_SEQ")
 @SequenceGenerator(name="PERSON_SEQ", sequenceName="PERSON_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
 private Long id;


 @Column(unique=true)
 private String username;
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Test1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

</session-factory>
```

Comment: How did you determine that constraint is ignored?

Comment: the constraint is not passed to the db.
Also, i test it and it let me create duplicate usernames

Answer (score 1):

Just set property "hbm2ddl.auto" to "create" and hibernate will recreate table with unique column.